# How does A(): this(Default) work?

Tags: c#, constructor

In a library (OpenTK) I saw a weird **constructor** of some class. The class has a static class member containing an instance of the class with default values for all the fields.

It looked like this (this is not the actual implementation, just something to make it clear):

```
class A {
    public int number;
    public static A Default = new A(0);

    public A(): this(Default) { }

    public A(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

What I'm wondering is how the first ctor works. Well probably the resulting A instance will be a copy of Default but what ctor of A is called for this(Default)? It confuses me because c# doesn't have copy constructors and there were no explicit constructors of A declared that accept an instance of it.

I searched the net but I have no clue how this phenomenon is called so that didn't work. Also, MS's docs on c# didn't mention this is possible, as far as I saw atleast.

Does anyone know the details of this?

Platform:
**VS 2010 SP1**, **.NET 4.5**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How does it work? It doesn't, the code you posted won't compile. You're right that there are no copy constructors in C#, so if you wanted one, you would need to write it. Something like:

```
public A(A a) : this(a.number) {}
```

Another possibility would be that there was an implicit conversion from `A` to `int`.

Comment: You're right. There indeed was another ctor that accepted an instance of the class acting as a copy constructor. I saw it just now because the code is a bit messy -_-.